# Where to use and what to use alias or ln -s or PATH (what is the specific difference)

Tags: symlink, path, alias

I have idea about `alias` and `ln -s` and `PATH`. Recently, i had some issue once I installed some softwares in my Debian box. While I tried to start the program, it says `No such file or directory` (in console).

So, I just found the bin path of that application and created `softlink` to `/usr/bin/`. Then it works fine.

And I just tried to do the same with setting up `alias` name to that bin file and Works fine.

And same with by adding this `bin` path to `PATH` variable. And everything works fine (Anyway, only one option is fine for me).

Is there any specific difference When do I need to use what? Am I violating anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're entirely different things, though in this case they can be used for similar purposes.

This:

```
alias appl="/Applications/path/to/bin/appl"
```

creates an alias, so that typing `appl` on the command line is equivalent to typing `/Applications/path/to/bin/appl`.

`ln -s`, on the other hand, creates a *symbolic link* in the file system.  A symbolic link is a reference to another file, and for most purposes it can be treated as if it were the file itself. It applies to anything that accesses it, not just to the shell, it's immediately visible to all processes running on the system, and it persists until it's removed. (A symbolic link is implemented as a small special file containing the name of the target file.)